# Cant create user with django-knox

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am having issues creating a user

```
serializer.py
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from .models import Invoice


class CreateUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Userfields = ('id', 'username', 'password')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create_user(validated_data['username'],
                                        None,
                                        validated_data['password'])
        return user


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = "__all__"
```

This is the error message I am getting. 
tuple' object has no attribute '_meta'

Comment: can you add more infos about the error, pls?

Comment: @Ricardo when I go to localhost:8000/auth/register this error pops up, but all the other routes make perfectly. it seems the issue is how a created the user